# Everyone and plural usage

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

"Everyone want their homes to be at the centres of cities"
Is this correct usage or is there any alternative way to convey the same?

Comment: Everyone wants their homes to be in the city centers... This is a language learner question.

Comment: No. _Every_ and _each_ (and all their compounds) are singular, not plural. They are part of grammar and their meaning is about choosing, not number. _All_ is plural, same reason; while _any_ and _none_ can be either singular or plural.

Comment: @John Lawler... If this is wrong usage, what is the proper usage to convey the exact information using a different sentence construction

Comment: First get the grammar right. There are a lot of other mistakes in the sentence and you need to get them right before you start worrying about coordinating quantifiers. It's impossible to convey exact information when the construction is poor.